# C# how to do a does not contain with a contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list where I trying to query data that contains some information but not other. 
So: MgrName contains userName, or Name contains userName and if so Name does not contain currentUser.Text

```
var query = from bCal in dc.ListData
            where bCal.MgrName.Contains(userName) || 
                  (bCal.Name.Contains(userName) && bCal.Name != currentUser.Text)
             select bCal;
```

instead of using the

```
&& bCal.Name != currentUser.Text
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
 where bCal.MgrName.Contains(userName) || (bCal.Name.Contains(userName) && !(bCal.Name.Contains(currentUser.Text)))
```

but when trying it this way I get an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: why did this question get a negative? i would appreciate comments when  negative so that I can improve the question

Comment: Can you share the type that `dc.ListData` is and what that looks like?

Comment: Is bCal.Name a string or list? Contains on a string is the same as "Like" whereas with a list, it's equivalent to "in". That being said, if MgrName or Name are Null, you will get the Object reference not set exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `bCal.Name` or `currentUser.Text` is null (given that `!=` works). Other than that I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: If the first code works but the second doesn't, then the only thing it can really be is currentUser.Text, but I didn't know that calling string.contains(null) returned an error?  if currentUser was null, then the first code would have the same error...

Comment: The current.text is not null

Comment: Then it must be `bCal.Name` that is null.

Comment: @Nevyn if `currentUser.Text` was `null`, `ArgumentNullException` would be thrown instead of `NullReferenceException`

Comment: it's not null either. strange...let me see if I can get a more detailed error

Comment: well, in general null reference indicates that you are attempting to perform SOME operation on a null.  Not sure what to say beyond that.  The only advice I can really offer is nullCheck everything.  `String.IsNullOrEmpty` gets used a lot in my code.